# Passing a variable into a Bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am able to pass the variable to the bootstrap 3 modal at the bottom of the modal where it says  id="callId"  but how do I pass the callID to the modal where I have  $test = callId .

```
<a data-id="<?=$sid?>" data-conf="<?=$call_conf?>" class="open-AddCallDialog btn btn-success btn-xs" href="#addCallDialog">Call Borrower</a>
```

The jquery script

```
$(document).on("click", ".open-AddCallDialog", function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var _self = $(this);

    var myCallId = _self.data('id');
    $("#callId").val(myCallId);

    $(_self.attr('href')).modal('show');
});
```

The Modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="addCallDialog"> tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Call Borrower</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
      <div class="row well">
       $test = call_conf;



      </div>
      </div>
       <div class="modal-footer">
        <input name="id" id="callId" type="hidden" value=""/> 
        <input name="pid" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $pid;?>"/>
        <input name="processtp" type="hidden" value="callborrower"/>
        <button id="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-xs center">Update</button>
      </div>
      </form>
      </div>

    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
```

Comment: It isn't very clear for me. Can you fix grammar and explain what you want to obtain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few events that are fired when bootstrap modals are created / destroyed.

The one you need is `shown.bs.modal` that is fired once the modal is shown and all CSS3 animations are complete. By hooking into this event you can add data to the modal's DOM structure.

```
$(document).on('click', '.openAddCallDialog', function(event)
{
    var _self = $(this),
        id = _self.data('id'),
        conf = _self.data('conf'),
        modalEl = $(_self.attr('href'));

    modalEl.modal('show').one('shown.bs.modal', function(event)
    {            
        // This function body is the modal shown event callback
        // You can do anything in this function to modify the DOM
        // within the shown modal.

        var modal = $(this);

        modal.find('#callId').val(callId);

        modal.find('.well').text(conf);
    });;
}
```

Comment: Can I add two variables with this script

Comment: Sure, just get the variables you need and then add them to the modal in the callback.

Comment: I changed the link above with the variable That I want to add and I added it to the modal where I want it to show up. Sorry I should have put this in my original question. I do not understand your answer above where you say in the callback.

Comment: Modified the answer to show you what I mean by callback and also add in the `conf` data for you.

Comment: I am understanding the DOM stuff. Where I can have it find anything in modal. But now it will not open the modal it was opening before I changed the code

Comment: Could you point me to where I can read about doing this so I can learn more about it

Comment: Changed the code where 'modalEl' wasn't being set properly. The events stuff is one the jQuery manual, and the bootstrap modal events are all listed in the BS3 docs under modals.